# iOS AutoLayouts, wrong UIView frame

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview

I have an xib file and I want my green UIView to change its height according to Device, but whenever I want to get it height with methods

`[self.tablePlaceView frame];
[self.tablePlaceView bounds];`

it returns {{0, 0}, {320, 568}} on all Devices, but on previews and device it does everything right.

[image: http://imageshack.com/a/img673/1600/zyMVoV.png]

Comment: when do you call that methods? try to call it in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`...

Comment: what do you mean with all devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by default your view get its size from your NIB file. after constraints take action, you'll be able to see the real frame in viewDidAppear: method